# layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf error while adding HelloWorld app in Android source code

Tags: android, makefile, dependencies

I create a HelloWorld application following Android's [official link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project). It runs fine in the Android Studio Emulator. I take the same application folder and add it in the `packages/app/` folder of Android source code. Then I add the name of the app in `build/target/product/core.mk` file. Then I add an Android.mk in the app folder which looks like the following:

```
ROOT_LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
$(info Start building SohamFirstApp from path $(ROOT_LOCAL_PATH) ...)

include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
include $(ROOT_LOCAL_PATH)/app/src/main/Android.mk
```

The app/src/main/Android.mk looks like:

```
MAIN_LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
# Call to build JNI libs
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
LOCAL_PATH := $(MAIN_LOCAL_PATH)

$(info Entering $(LOCAL_PATH) ...)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := SohamFirstApp

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled

LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES := libnative-lib

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES := \
    android-support-v4 \
    android-support-v7-recyclerview \
    android-support-v7-preference \
    android-support-v7-appcompat \
    android-support-v14-preference \
    android-support-v17-preference-leanback \
    android-support-v17-leanback \
    android-support-v4 \

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    $(call all-java-files-under, java)

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/res 

LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := \
    --auto-add-overlay 

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

But when I compile Android, I get the following error:

```
packages/apps/SohamFirstApp/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:9: error: attribute 'com.example.sohamfirstapp:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf' not found.
packages/apps/SohamFirstApp/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:9: error: attribute 'com.example.sohamfirstapp:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' not found.
packages/apps/SohamFirstApp/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:9: error: attribute 'com.example.sohamfirstapp:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf' not found.
packages/apps/SohamFirstApp/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:9: error: attribute 'com.example.sohamfirstapp:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' not found.
```

I have checked my Android Studio Emulator Android version and the Android source code Android version to be both Android 8.1
What is the reason of this error? and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`constraint-layout` and `constraint-layout-solver` needed to be added in the app in AOSP. I added that. The process is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58738288/9605189

Answer (score 0):

Think that the `Android.mk` might be missing `com.android.support.constraint` and that
`packages/apps/SohamFirstApp/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml` should be:

```
android:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf=""
android:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf=""
android:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf=""
android:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf=""
```

Comment: Where should I add that in `Android.mk`? `app/build.gradle` already has `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'` in the dependencies. I did what you said to do in `activity.xml`, but got the same error.

Comment: @SohamSinha the name-space should become known when added below `LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES`; the Gradle dependencies do not really matter primarily, because it will not fetch them, so they need to be provided. The error message might be a subsequent error of not having provided the library.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying. Do you know what line exactly I should add in Android.mk?

Comment: `android-support-constraint` needs to be provided as `LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES`.

Comment: It now says: error: SohamFirstApp (APPS android-x86) missing android-support-constraint (JAVA_LIBRARIES android-x86)